# Python Class Function not Working Correctly

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the below code which I have written in PyCharm.  I can't figure out why it won't run correctly and print out "Chuck".  When I run the code in PyCharm I get the follow message "Process finish with exit code 0".  I am trying to learn Python and follow along with a YouTube playlist but I keep getting stuck here.  Thank you in advance!

```
class class_name:
def createName(self, name):
    self.name=name
def display_name(self):
    return self.name
def saying(self):
    print("hello %s" % self.name)

first=class_name()
second=class_name()
first.createName('Chuck')
second.createName('tony')
first.display_name()
```

Comment: your call to `first.display_name()` is just returning the name. You need to actually print it. `print(first.display_name())`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class class_name:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def display_name(self):
        return self.name
    def saying(self):
        print("hello %s" % self.name)

first = class_name('Chuck')
second = class_name('Tony')
print(first.display_name()) #Chuck
```

As first.display_name() returns a string you need to use print to display the value in your terminal.

Answer (score -1):

**Hello Chuck0185**

**First read this best website before start Python 3,**
1. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/
2. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/
3. https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/

**Difference between python 2 and python 3,**
1. http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html
2. https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-major-differences-between-Python-2-and-Python-3

**Pycharm tools knowledge for best site,**
1. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/creating-and-running-your-first-python-project.html

**Try this code,** 
Using python2:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Using python 2
class class_name:
    def createName(self, name):
        self.name=name
    def display_name(self):
        return self.name
    def saying(self):
        print("hello %s" % self.name)

first=class_name()
second=class_name()

first.createName('Chuck')
second.createName('tony')

print "First Name is: %s" % first.display_name()
print "Second Name is: %s" % second.display_name()

first.saying()
second.saying()
```

Using python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Using python 3
class class_name:
    def createName(self, name):
        self.name=name
    def display_name(self):
        return self.name
    def saying(self):
        print("hello %s" % self.name)

first=class_name()
second=class_name()

first.createName('Chuck')
second.createName('tony')

print("First Name is: %s" % first.display_name())
print("Second Name is: %s" % second.display_name())

first.saying()
second.saying()
```

I hope my answer is useful for you.